# SUMIF Multiple Conditions

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have a quick spreadsheet I'm throwing together:

```
=SUMIF(D12:D,"=Austin",B12:C)
=SUMIF(D12:D,"=Corey",B12:C)
```

These work fine. The data for D is based on a drop down with the values `Austin`, `Corey`, `Both`.

The data for B & C is: `|Amount | Qty |`. However, if you use:

```
=SUMIF(D12:D,{"=Austin","=Both"},B12:C)
```

it returns only `Austin` results.

How would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work as an array formula (eg entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

[image: SO25751641 example]

Comment: Could you show me an example? Tried a couple different ways and still doesn't work. Edit: It does work, but it puts the value for the second value in the next cell